# What is the NIST recommended maximum bias for random number generators?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, nist

What is the maximum bias recommended by NIST for random number generators?

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89167/83961) says that it is $2^{-64}$.

Is it same for all applications? Does NIST have a publication with more information?

I tried to browse through [NIST Recommendation for Random Bit Generator Constructions](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/sp/800-90c/draft/documents/draft-sp800-90c.pdf), but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NIST recommends $\epsilon \le 2^{-64}$. They consider such a sequence to have *"full entropy"*.  It's in the definitions (page 4) of SP800-90C.

[image: grab]

[Converting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20-log2%280.5%20%2B%20%282%5E-x%29%29%20%3D%201-2%5E%28-64%29) that to a probability bias, $P(x_i = 0, x_i = 1) \approx 0.5 \pm 2^{-66}$.

The interesting thing is that if the [Leftover Hash Lemma](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/088.pdf) is used, $\epsilon$ can be set by the designer.  [ID Quantique](https://www.idquantique.com/random-number-generation/overview/) TRNGs are designed with extractors such that $\epsilon \approx  2^{-100}$.